react-google-maps API is not loading using useMapsLibrary hook
I am using react-google-maps to develop a small React application.
As per the below link a particular Google API can be loaded using the useMapsLibrary hook
https://visgl.github.io/react-google-maps/docs/api-reference/hooks/use-maps-library
I am using the hook to load the geocoding API, but seems the API is not loading at all.
I have checked:

The API key is correct.
The API is enabled in the console.
No restrictions on the API.
It Doesn't matter but the Map ID is also correct.
The MarkerWithInfoWindow component is rendering fine with no issues.

Console prints:
API Loaded: false
Maps.tsx:21 Status: NOT_LOADED
Maps.tsx:22 Geocoder Library: null


It does not go inside the handleGeocode function at all. What is wrong? Thanks!
Below is the React component code:
import {
    APILoadingStatus,
    APIProvider,
    Map,
    useApiIsLoaded,
    useApiLoadingStatus,
    useMapsLibrary
} from "@vis.gl/react-google-maps";
import MarkerWithInfoWindow from "./MarkerWithInfoWindow";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const Maps = () => {
    const geocoderLib = useMapsLibrary('geocoding');
    const apiIsLoaded = useApiIsLoaded();
    const status = useApiLoadingStatus();
    const [markerPostion, setMarkerPosition] = useState({ lat: 53.54992, lng: 10.00678 });


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("API Loaded:", apiIsLoaded);
        console.log("Status:", status);
        console.log("Geocoder Library:", geocoderLib);
        const handleGeocode = () => {
            console.log(`geocoderLib1`, status, apiIsLoaded, geocoderLib)
            if (status !== APILoadingStatus.LOADED || !geocoderLib) return;

            // const { country, city, address } = formData;
            const fullAddress = `fullAddress`;

            const geocoder = new geocoderLib.Geocoder();

            void geocoder.geocode({ address: fullAddress }, (results, status) => {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    console.log(`Geocode successful: ${results}`);
                    // setMarkerPosition({ lat: location.lat(), lng: location.lng() });
                    setMarkerPosition({lat: 53.54992, lng: 10.00678})
                    // map.setCenter(location);
                } else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });
        };
        if (apiIsLoaded && status === APILoadingStatus.LOADED) {
            handleGeocode();
        }

    }, [apiIsLoaded, status, geocoderLib])

    return (
        <APIProvider apiKey=<apiKey>>
            <Map
                style={{width: '50vw', height: '50vh'}}
                defaultCenter={{lat: 53.54992, lng: 10.00678}}
                zoom={5}
                mapId=<mapId>
                gestureHandling={'greedy'}
                disableDefaultUI={true}
                >
                <MarkerWithInfoWindow position={markerPostion} />
            </Map>
        </APIProvider>
    )
}

export default Maps



If the function isn't being called you'll probably be able to narrow it down to apiIsLoaded && status === APILoadingStatus.LOADED. What are the values of those variables?

I am printing those values and in the console I can see:
API Loaded: false
Maps.tsx:21 Status: NOT_LOADED

So, that's the reason then. To call that function apiLoaded must be true and status must be LOADED. Since we don't know how apiLoaded and status are updated there's not a lot for SO to help you with here, but it should give you enough information to debug your code and figure out where the state updates are going wrong.

Yes I mean these values are provided by native hooks and I am stuck there only, thanks anyways!

Your API key is not being provided correctly in your component. Please wrap you parent component Maps with 


<APIProvider apiKey=<apiKey>>
<Map>
..
</Map>
</APIProvider>



Instead provide it in parent component , I think its Maps


<APIProvider apiKey=<apiKey>>
<Maps>
..
</Maps>
</APIProvider>



